# React with Semantic UI, Dynamically Add Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Semantic-UI has this React component, [**Segment**](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/segment) that I am using.

In my application, I am using onMouseOver with Segment, like so:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Segment onMouseOver={this.handleHover} />
    );
  }
```

What I want handleHover() to do is to dynamically add semantic UI props to Segment on the mouse over event. I tried doing this with [**react clone element**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), and adding a new color prop according to the Semantic UI docs

React docs state:

> Clone and return a new React element using element as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element's props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly.

```
handleHover() {
    React.cloneElement(Segment, {
      color: "teal"                  //NEWLY ADDED
    });

    //THIS EXECUTES SO EVENT IS TRIGGERING.
    console.log("I'm in here");
  }
```

So even after cloning the React Component, it still doesn't show the new color attribute when I hover over the Segment.

**Question:** Is this the right approach to dynamically adding props? If so then why isn't the newly added color being shown. If not then how should I change my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add whatever prop value you want to the state of your current component, and change that value `onMouseOver`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    propValue: undefined
  }
  this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this);
}

handleHover(event) {
  this.setState({propValue: 'hover'});
}

render() {
  return (
    <Segment onMouseOver={this.handleHover} propName={this.state.propValue} />
  );
}
```

The value of `this.state.propValue` will change from `undefined` to `hover`, and the `Segment` component will get that new prop when the `onMouseOver` callback get called.

> You can change `propName` to `color` and `this.state.propValue` to `'teal'`, based on your example.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Warning: Unknown prop `propValue` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element.

Comment: You should use properties that `Segment` allow :)

Comment: Read the last note in my answer

Comment: hmm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below are the two snippets of code

Comment: handleHover(event) {
    this.setState({ propValue: "color" });
  }

Comment: <Segment
        onMouseOver={this.handleHover}
        propValue="teal"
      >

Comment: `propValue` should be a prop that `Segment` allow. The full list is in the link in your question. You should use one of them (for example: color/size/textAlign)

Comment: Cool it works :), very elegant answer too compared to cloning the entire element. Thanks so much!